# Drag and drop full calendar doesn't fire php script

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, fullcalendar

Using fullcalendar with php scripts for submitting the ajax through to php/myql connection.

I've added a drag and drop feature to the page/fullcalendar and it renders fine on the page, works, and no problems. When you normally click and type an event, its fires the script and uses PHP to add via mysql.

The problem is, once the drag and drop element has been dropped on the calendar, I need to execute the same script as if you were to use when its clicked and typed on. I might have been working on this for too long as now I've confused myself!

Script is:

```
<script>

 $(document).ready(function() {
  var date = new Date();
  var d = date.getDate();
  var m = date.getMonth();
  var y = date.getFullYear();

  // initialize the external events
  // -----------------------------------------------------------------

  $("#external-events .fc-event").each(function() {
    // store data so the calendar knows to render an event upon drop
    $(this).data("event", {
      title: $.trim($(this).text()), // use the element's text as the event title
      stick: true // maintain when user navigates (see docs on the renderEvent method)
    });

    // make the event draggable using jQuery UI
    $(this).draggable({
      zIndex: 999,
      revert: true, // will cause the event to go back to its
      revertDuration: 0 //  original position after the drag
    });
  });



  var calendar = $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
   editable: true,
      droppable: true, // this allows things to be dropped onto the calendar
    drop: function() {
      // is the "remove after drop" checkbox checked?
      if ($('#drop-remove').is(':checked')) {
        // if so, remove the element from the "Draggable Events" list
        $(this).remove();
      }
    },
    defaultView: 'agendaWeek',
    nowIndicator: true,
     weekends: false,
      firstday: 1,
   forceEventDuration: true,
    timezoneParam: 'UTC',
   header: {
    left: 'prev,next today',
    center: 'title',
    right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
   },
businessHours: {
  // days of week. an array of zero-based day of week integers (0=Sunday)
  dow: [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 ], // Monday - Friday

  start: '07:00', // a start time (10am in this example)
  end: '19:00', // an end time (6pm in this example)
},
   events: "get/engineer_events.php",

   eventRender: function(event, element, view) {
    if (event.allDay === 'true') {
     event.allDay = true;
    } else {
     event.allDay = false;
    }
   },
   selectable: true,
   selectHelper: true,
   select: function(start, end, allDay) {
   var title = prompt('Event Title:');

   if (title) {
   var start = $.fullCalendar.formatDate(start, "Y-MM-DD HH:mm:ss");
   var end = $.fullCalendar.formatDate(end, "Y-MM-DD HH:mm:ss");
   $.ajax({
       url: 'process/add_events.php',
       data: 'title='+ title+'&start='+ start +'&end='+ end,
       type: "POST",
       success: function(json) {
       alert('Added Successfully');
       }
   });
   calendar.fullCalendar('renderEvent',
   {
       title: title,
       start: start,
       end: end,
   },
   true
   );
   }
   calendar.fullCalendar('unselect');
   },

   editable: true,
   eventDrop: function(event, delta) {
   var start = $.fullCalendar.formatDate(event.start, "Y-MM-DD HH:mm:ss");
   var end = $.fullCalendar.formatDate(event.end, "Y-MM-DD HH:mm:ss");
   $.ajax({
       url: 'process/update_events.php',
       data: 'title='+ event.title+'&start='+ start +'&end='+ end +'&id='+ event.id ,
       type: "POST",
       success: function(json) {
        alert("Your event has been added.");
       }
   });
   },
   eventClick: function(event) {
    var decision = confirm("Woah, you're about to delete this, are you sure?"); 
    if (decision) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "process/delete_event.php",
        data: "&id=" + event.id,
         success: function(json) {
             $('#calendar').fullCalendar('removeEvents', event.id);
              alert("Updated successfully");}
    });
    }
    },
   eventResize: function(event) {
       var start = $.fullCalendar.formatDate(event.start, "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
       var end = $.fullCalendar.formatDate(event.end, "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
       $.ajax({
        url: 'process/update_events.php',
        data: 'title='+ event.title+'&start='+ start +'&end='+ end +'&id='+ event.id ,
        type: "POST",
        success: function(json) {
         alert("Event updated successfully");
        }
       });
    }

  });

 });

</script>
```

Comment: Need more debugging info regarding what actual happens in the drop event and if request is made inspect it in browser dev tools network to see status, what is actually sent and returned(if) any

Comment: probably not your issue, but what fullCalendar version are you using? `$.fullCalendar.formatDate` was deprecated after v1, it's not in the docs anymore and you can't be certain it's reliable. Assuming you're not still stuck on v1, then you should be using momentJS to format dates. Since fullCalendar supplies its dates as moment objects already, you can simply do something like `event.start.format("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")`. See also http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/

Comment: Anyway, is the problem occurring for externally dropped events, or internally dropped events, or internally resized events, or all, or some combination of the 3? You trigger ajax requests for the internal drop/resize, but not for external drops. Like charlieftl said, check in your browser's developer tools to see what's actually happening - e.g. set breakpoints to see where your code runs, watch for console errors, ajax status etc. There's nothing _obviously_ wrong with what you've written.

Comment: using version 3.4. All the internal events are working, its only affecting the external event thats are dropped, they drop, stick but dont fire the required ajax to write to the php script.

I guess what I need to do is link the external drop to the same ajax, what code would be needed for that though?

Comment: @ADyson I was thinking I might need to put the ajax into the drop function? I tried putting an alert there, triggers at when the event is dropped but then this doesn't like this:

    drop: function() {
   var start = $.fullCalendar.formatDate(start, "Y-MM-DD HH:mm:ss");
   var end = $.fullCalendar.formatDate(end, "Y-MM-DD HH:mm:ss");
   $.ajax({
    url: 'process/add_events.php',
    data: 'title='+ title+'&start='+ start +'&end='+ end,
    type: "POST",
    success: function(json) {
    alert('Added Successfully');
    }
   });

Comment: "doesn't like" means what? It pulled a face? ;-) If you get some sort of error you'll need to tell me what it is. Also please don't post more than tiny amounts of code in the comments, it's very hard to read. Update the question with it - cheers.